# Should I be starting and stopping a UIActivityIndicator instance on the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

**Example:**

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *favObjects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *favObject in favObjects) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell setSizeLabel:[_arrayOfSizes objectAtIndex:[[favObject valueForKey:@"size"] integerValue]]];
            [[cell sizeDropDownButton] setTitle:[cell sizeLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });

        if ([[[cell currentObject] valueForKey:@"alternativeColour"] boolValue]) {

            // Colours are stored in db on parse as numbers, I use array below to determine which colour is being red back by valueForkey below

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [cell setColourLabel:[_arrayOfColours objectAtIndex:[[favObject valueForKey:@"colour"] integerValue]]];
                [[cell colourDropDownButton] setTitle:[cell colourLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            });
        }

        [[cell priceLabelSpinner] stopAnimating];
        [[cell titleLabelSpinner] stopAnimating];
        [[cell sizeDropDownButton] setHidden:NO];
        [[cell colourDropDownButton] setHidden:NO];

    }

}];
```

You can see I'm setting the the buttons label titles on the main queue. However below I'm stopping a the spinned on the background queue as well as unhiding buttons. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that can cause you view change should be called from main thread:

> Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the
>   main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView
>   class from code running in the main thread of your application. The
>   only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view
>   object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main
>   thread.

So taking into account what's suggested by Apple you should rewrite your code to:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *favObjects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *favObject in favObjects) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell setSizeLabel:[_arrayOfSizes objectAtIndex:[[favObject valueForKey:@"size"] integerValue]]];
            [[cell sizeDropDownButton] setTitle:[cell sizeLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });

        if ([[[cell currentObject] valueForKey:@"alternativeColour"] boolValue]) {

            // Colours are stored in db on parse as numbers, I use array below to determine which colour is being red back by valueForkey below

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [cell setColourLabel:[_arrayOfColours objectAtIndex:[[favObject valueForKey:@"colour"] integerValue]]];
                [[cell colourDropDownButton] setTitle:[cell colourLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            });
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cell priceLabelSpinner] stopAnimating];
            [[cell titleLabelSpinner] stopAnimating];
            [[cell sizeDropDownButton] setHidden:NO];
            [[cell colourDropDownButton] setHidden:NO];
        });

    }

}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Stopping animating or hiding views are also UI operations, so they must be done on main thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per `Apple Documentation` all `UI` updates should happen in main thread. So have modified your code and also include all `UI` updates in single `dispatch_async` block, try below:-

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *favObjects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *favObject in favObjects) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell setSizeLabel:[_arrayOfSizes objectAtIndex:[[favObject valueForKey:@"size"] integerValue]]];
            [[cell sizeDropDownButton] setTitle:[cell sizeLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([[[cell currentObject] valueForKey:@"alternativeColour"] boolValue]) {

        // Colours are stored in db on parse as numbers, I use array below to determine which colour is being red back by valueForkey below
            [cell setColourLabel:[_arrayOfColours objectAtIndex:[[favObject valueForKey:@"colour"] integerValue]]];
            [[cell colourDropDownButton] setTitle:[cell colourLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    [[cell priceLabelSpinner] stopAnimating];
    [[cell titleLabelSpinner] stopAnimating];
    [[cell sizeDropDownButton] setHidden:NO];
    [[cell colourDropDownButton] setHidden:NO];

}

}];
```